# How to check if time string(without date part) is in H:i:s format php

Tags: php, datetime, formatting, timestamp

I have time strings as follows

8:7:9

17:34:38

I want to check if the strings have H:i:s format if I found completely invalid strings like empty,other text values, strings with date part (2017:10:12 18:39:21)

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: I would put it in the constructor of `\DateTime()` so for example `new \DateTime("2017-10-08 8:7:9")` will create instance of DateTime sucessfully, also 17:34:38 , but  `\DateTime("2017-10-08 25:70:9")` or  `\DateTime("2017-10-08 string")`will fail. One thing you can do it manually is not to put empty string to constructor becasue it creates valid DateTime with `00:00:00` time.

Comment: I can get a valid time using date("H:i:s", strtotime($value) this. but when I have a string 'kkkdls' it gives a timezone time I guess..will need to go for pregmatch

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime` to check whether a string matches a specific time format:

```
if (!DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '2017-10-08 17:23:30')) {
    // time string does not match the H:i:s format
}
```

If the string matches the provided format, the result will be a `DateTime` object. If it doesn't, the result will be a boolean `false`. So you can easily check for that.

Comment: hey @ishegg check out my answer if you needed to know one

Comment: @ishegg correct, because that's not a valid `H:i:s` formatted time string. `H:i:s` requires leading zeroes for hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: right, that's what I meant. That's OP's first example so it needs to work for that.

Comment: @ishegg OP's question was "I want to check if the strings have H:i:s format" which that first string doesn't (it's not a valid time string in *any* natively supported time format). OP's own answer will work for that case.

Comment: @rickdenhaan yeah, agreed. It's a mismatch between his request and his examples.

Answer (score 0):

I first went with a regex match like below

```
if(preg_match("/\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}/",$value))
{
}
```

Then applied the split and validated the individual time part for 24, 60 and 60